# Multiple viewports in ToggleWindow

Tags: ocean

I have a toggle window (with `2D` graphic) with several `Viewports`. How do I now which `Viewport` that is active? Is there an `API` where I can get access to the `Viewports`? I haven't found any documentation about this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! We encourage you to [research your questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you've [tried something already](http://whathaveyoutried.com/), please add it to the question - if not, research and attempt your question first, and then come back.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Ocean API yet to access the Viewports. There is, however a new API introduced in Ocean 2012.1 which makes it possible to extend available Viewports, i.e. add your custom toggle windows to 2D Plot window.